# How to get  ancestors of a class in Coderush?

Tags: coderush, coderush-xpress, dxcore

I was trying to get all ancestors (Classes and Interfaces) of a Class to a list.

I tried this code but did not work.

```
 public static List<Class> AncestorList;



 public static void GetAncestorList(Class curClass)
    {


      if(curClass.PrimaryAncestorType!=null)
      {
          Class primaryAncestor = curClass.PrimaryAncestorType.Resolve(new SourceTreeResolver()) as Class;
          if(primaryAncestor !=null)
          {
              AncestorList.Add(primaryAncestor);//Add primary ancestor to the list.

              GetAncestorList(primaryAncestor);//find the ancestors of the primary ancestor.
          }
          foreach (TypeReferenceExpression typ1 in curClass.SecondaryAncestorTypes  )
          {
              Class secAncestor = typ1.Resolve(new SourceTreeResolver()) as Class;
              if(secAncestor !=null)
              {
                  AncestorList.Add(secAncestor);//Add secondary ancestor to the list.
                  GetAncestorList(secAncestor);//find ancestors of secondary ancestor.
              }
          }
      }
```

In this part of code I tried to collect all the classes and interfaces into  AncestorList. 
But when I tried to find number classes in the list it showed 0. The test project had few parent classes and interfaces. Please help to find the error.

I made a Call to the GetAncestorList function in the  following way.

```
AncestorList=new List<Class>();
GetAncestorList(currentClass);
```

Thanks in Advance,

Vinod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better method to get all ancestors of a class:

```
ITypeElement[] ancestors = curClass.GetBaseTypes();
```

or this one:

```
ITypeElement[] ancestors = CodeRush.Source.GetAllBaseTypes(curClass);
```

But these calls will return instances of ITypeElement type - it depends on how you are going to use instances of ancestors. If you'd like to convert ITypeElement into a Class instance, use the following code:

```
  foreach (ITypeElement ancestor in ancestors)
  {
    Class classInstance = ancestor.ToLanguageElement() as Class;
    if (classInstance != null)
      AncestorList.Add(classInstance);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Alex,  _CodeRush.Source.GetAllBaseTypes(curClass);_  is really a good function...:)  I was struggling for 3 days with above code and other tries ..Your answer really helped me..Thank you again..